# How to put a list of cells into a submodule in yosys

Tags: yosys

I am trying to write a procedure to put each Strongly Connected Component of the given circuit into a distinct sub-module.

So, I tried to add a function to SCC pass in Yosys to add each SCC into a submod. The function is:

```
  void putSelectionIntoParition (RTLIL::Design *design, 
                 std::vector<pair<std::string,RTLIL::Selection>>& SelectionVector)
  {
    int p_count = 0;
    for (std::vector<pair<std::string,RTLIL::Selection>>::iterator it = SelectionVector.begin();
     it != SelectionVector.end(); ++it) 
      {
    design->selection_stack[0] = it->second;
    design->selection_stack[0].optimize(design);
    std::string command = "submod -name ";
    command.append(it->first);
    Pass::call_on_selection(design, it->second, command); 
    ++p_count;
    } 
  }
```

However, my code does not work properly. 
I guess the problem is with "selection" process that I use. I was wondering if there is any utility/API inside the yosys source that accept vector of cells (as well and a name submodule) and put them into a sub-module.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work just fine:

```
void putSelectionIntoParition(RTLIL::Design *design,
    std::vector<pair<std::string, RTLIL::Selection>> &SelectionVector)
{
    for (auto it : SelectionVector) {
        std::string command = "submod -name " + it.first;
        Pass::call_on_selection(design, it.second, command);
    }
}
```

You definitely don't need (nor should) modify `selection_stack`.

> I was wondering if there is any utility/API inside the yosys source that accept vector of cells (as well and a name submodule) and put them into a sub-module.

You would do this by setting the `submod="<name>"` attribute on the cells. Then simply run the `submod` command.

You might have seen that the `scc` documentation mentions a `-set_attr` option that is yet unimplemented. I have now implemented this option in commit `ef603c6` (commit `914aa8a` contains a bugfix for `scc`).

With this feature you can now accomplished what you have described using something like the following yosys script.

```
read_verilog test.v
prep
scc -set_attr submod scc{}
submod
show test
```

I have tested this with the folling `test.v` file:

```
module test(input A, B, output X, Y);
assign X = (A & B) ^ X, Y = A | (B ^ Y);
endmodule
```

[image]

```
3. Executing SCC pass (detecting logic loops).
Found an SCC: $xor$test.v:2$2
Found an SCC: $or$test.v:2$4 $xor$test.v:2$3
Found 2 SCCs in module test.
Found 2 SCCs.
```

Comment: I guess I found a bug there. I explained it in my main post. Please let me know if you want more explanations or examples.

Comment: @Mehrdad in its default mode, `scc` does not consider FF cells or hierarchical cells, thus your `up_counter` does not contain a loop as far as `scc` is concerned. Use `-all_cell_types` to overwrite (see `help scc`). Flatten your design (e.g. using `prep -flatten`) if you'd like to find logic loops that span multiple hierarchical cells with `scc`.

Comment: @Mehrdad I did try it and it works just fine here. Please edit your question and state what exactly you are doing, what the expected result is and how the result you get differs from that.

Comment: I have update my post and added more details of the steps I am taking. (this is done by latest yosys). I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Mehrdad afaics this is exactly the expected result. Please state in what way you would have expected a different result. Your `top_counter` module does not contain any scc. I'm sure `scc` found the scc in `up_counter` as expected. Just run `show` on that module or look at the output produced by the SCC pass.

Comment: PS @Mehrdad: You should always try to amend your question with additional information, never get rid of your original question. Otherwise this will break the question-answer format of stack overflow. For the same reason you should post a new question if a new question comes up as result of a previous question, not just tack on more and more questions in the comments to an answer. Also make sure to always include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example in your question (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My fault. Sorry! I will adhere to the rules of stackoverflow next time. I will post it as a new question. and retract this one to the original one.

Comment: I guess there is a corner case that scc does not encapsulate the SCCs. I have simplified the design and reported the issue in GitHub.